# I'm new to C but I'm getting "Segmentation Faults" (Seg fault/SIGSEGV). Why?

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

When I try to run the following logic snippits, I get segmentation faults, why? Sometimes I don't get segmentation faults but instead I get odd output that does not make sense...

### 1. Changing a string's character

```
char *str       = "Hello!";
str[0]          = 'h'; // SIGSEGV
```

---

### 2. Modifying the value of a pointer

```
int *num_ptr;
*num_ptr = 6; // SIGSEGV
```

---

### 3. Using an array or pointer returned from a function

```
int *getPoint()
{
    int cords[2] = {10, 20};
    return cords;
}

/* ... */

int *point = getPoint();
int total  = point[0] + point[1]; // SIGSEGV (or sometimes total = 0?)
```

---

### 4. Looping through n-sized array in function

```
void print_loop(int *array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
         printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]); // SIGSEGV
}

/* ... */
int nums[3] = {1, 2, 3};
print_loop(nums);
```

---

What do I do to fix each of these and understand why they happen?

Comment: segmentation faults are not for old C programmers

Comment: Segmentation faults are not a characteristic of C at all.  They are produced by *some* operating environments in which C programs run, and they are one possible manifestation of undefined behavior of C programs.

Comment: Although StackOverflow allows self-answered questions, the question itself must still be appropriate for SO.  This one is not, being far too broad.  Perhaps you were looking for [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation)?

Comment: I see this is a self-answered question, attempting to document a topic. I believe it would be better suited to the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) section of the site.

Comment: It covers too many issues to be a single post to be in documentation -- I attempted to make it this way because this question is not to go into binary detail but instead give short and quick answers, answers that normal entry level C programmers must gleam by looking at 5+ pages in doc. And, doc is still in beta and is very unpopular, when someone is asking a question in SO, doc does not show up in "similar questions" nor does it show up in a relevant google search and thus it leaves us with countless amount of dupes.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar, none of that makes this question appropriate for SO.  If you don't want to put the information in Documentation, whether in a single monolithic piece or in several, then I suggest starting a blog.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar, please understand that I do not mean to be harsh.  You are trying to provide something useful to other people, and that's commendable.  This just isn't a place for the form in which you've chosen to do it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger and Eugene Sh Specifically [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior#t=201701061836560865955)

Answer (score 3):

```
char *str;
int *num_ptr;
int *point;
```

^^ this code just creates a variable for you to then use which is a **pointer to memory**.  Realize it never allocates or reserves memory.

so for **2** where you do `*num_ptr = 6;` you are trying to put the value of 6 into memory pointed to by `num_ptr`.  But num_ptr does not point anywhere yet, it either points to **NULL** or is uninitialized and contains some random number value.  If it contains some random number value odds are it is not valid memory location, hence the segmentation violation.  And if it were NOT to result in a SIGSEV and the code ran then it would be by chance you got lucky; you would never want to program this way having basic concepts of programming happen by chance.

Same principle applies for all your other examples.  It doesn't matter the data type.  It's the basic problem of having a pointer to memory, and whether or not you have (by whatever means) reserved or allocated some valid range of storage space (RAM, disk, wherever).

```
str[0] = 'h';   is the same thing as            *str = 'h';
str[1] = 'h';   would be the equivalent of      *(str+1) = 'h';
str[2]          is                              *(str+2)
and so on,
where str is a pointer to the starting location of a range of memory,
then because str is of data type CHAR, +1 moves 1 byte, +2 moves 2 byte.
If it were of type INT where int is 4 bytes, then +1 would be the
initial memory location + 4.
```

Answer (score 1):

3. Using an array or pointer returned from a function

This doesnt't work, because you create a pointer and reserve a memory area inside a function, without malloc. When this function ends, you lose this reserved area.

So, you can't make a function that returns a pointer this way. Read a little about malloc() function.

5. Looping through n-sized array in function

This isn't the right way to loop through a n-sized array, sizeof return the number of bytes that you need tho allocate that structure, not how many elements you have in the array. A suggestion is by as a parameter how many elements you have, if it is a string, you can use strlen, from string.h.

Answer (score 0):

these are common pit falls when someone tries migrate to C from a virtual language such as Java, C#, Python, or JavaScript. The problem is that they do not understand the concept of memory management because virtual languages take care of that now. Hopefully new programmers wanting to learn C can be directed to this answer and avoid these pitfalls -- and ultimately prevent these types of questions from filling the front page of [`c`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) every day. I am going to be short worded as possible, as I know that 90% of you have already looked at this paragraph and said "lol tl;dr".

## What is a Segmentation Fault (seg fault)

It's when you try to access memory that's not yours. Or you try to write to memory that is read only -- The operating system is the one responsible for enforcing this.

An analogy: address in memory are like house address on the streets. And the things inside the houses would be the data itself. If you own a house, you go to its address and add and remove furniture as you please. If you don't own the house, you're simply breaking an entry and the police (The OS) arrest you (seg fault).

## Common ways to get it

#### P1. Changing a string's character

```
char *str       = "Hello!";
str[0]          = 'h'; // SIGSEGV
```

**Problem**: a string literal (declared within quotes, `"LIKE SO"`) may not be modified. Attempting to do so causes undefined behavior.

**Solution**: allocate your string in an array.

```
char str[]      = "Hello!";
str[0]          = 'h';
```

---

#### P2. Modifying the value of a pointer

```
int *num_ptr;
*num_ptr = 6; // SIGSEGV
```

**Problem**: `num` is pointer, but its address has not been defined. You can't derreference a pointer unless you give it a valid address.

**Solution**: Make sure you *point your pointers®*.

```
int *num_ptr;
int num;
num_ptr = &num; // num_ptr equals the address of num
*num_ptr = 6;
```

#### P3. Using an array or pointer returned from a function

```
int *getPoint()
{
    int cords[2] = {10, 20};
    return cords;
}

/* ... */

int *point = getPoint();
int total  = point[0] + point[1]; // SIGSEGV (or sometimes total = 0?)
```

**Problem**: `cords` is an array with automatic storage inside the function `getPoint()`. When this function returns, the array no longer exists, which means that `point` now points to invalid memory.

**Solution #1**: allocate `coords` with dynamic memory using, for example, `malloc()`. Dynamic memory exists as long as your program is running, or until you release it with `free()`.

```
int *getPoint()
{
    int *cords   = malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); // get 2 ints on permanent (heap) memory
    cords[0] = 10;
    cords[1] = 20;
    return cords;
}

/* ... */

int *point = getPoint();
int total  = point[0] + point[1];
free(point); // manual destroy
```

**Solution #2**: declare the array outside the function and pass its address to `getPoint()`. Now instead of returning the array, it *receives* and *modifies* it.

```
int *getPoint(int *cords)
{
    cords[0] = 10;
    cords[1] = 20;
    return cords;
}

/* ... */

int cords[2];
int *point = getPoint(chords);
int total  = point[0] + point[1]
```

#### P4. Looping through n-sized array in function

```
void print_loop(int *array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
         printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]); // SIGSEGV
}

/* ... */
int nums[3] = {1, 2, 3};
print_loop(nums);
```

**Problem**: In C, there is nothing holding your hand. This means you have to keep track of your own damn array lengths.

**Solution**: Whenever you pass an array into a function, you MUST also pass the size of the array.

```
void print_loop(int *array, int array_len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array_len; i++)
         printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
}

/* ... */
int nums[3] = {1, 2, 3};
print_loop(nums, 3);
```

## "My program does not have a seg fault and/or but it gives a strange result"

Seg faults and things that *should* cause seg faults are known as "undefined behavior". This means that the error will be different based on what compiler is used, what OS, what CPU, ect. Some cases there will not be an error at all, however that does not mean its OK. It's like saying "If OJ can get away with it then so can I" and then being surprised by the results.

Comment: There are a lot of things in this answer that are right, but there are also a lot of things that are only partially right or approximately right.  And there are a few things that are just wrong.  Overall, there are too many items to critique them all in comments.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know I must have missed some things. But instead of goading the incorrectness of my Q&A I wish that you help make it better.

Comment: I suggested an edition for the first items. The fourth example has many issues. The pointer declaration is wrong, the example should focus in only one string (`"Hello"`), and the text is a bit confusing with its mention to the length of the string and the size of the array. I stopped here. Anyway, maybe the author should consider editing the Wiki instead.

Comment: I am not goading you.  I am reiterating -- perhaps too obliquely -- that your question and answer are not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: I also missed some mentions to "permanent storage" in the previous examples. And I guess I made the second solution to the third problem  a bit more confusing by saying that the function does not return the pointer and not modifying it to not, you know, reutrn the pointer.

Comment: @giusti Removed P4 (and decremented P5 obviously). I was trying to hard to mention null terminators.